# minimized group of apps in windows 7 display as a window

Tags: windows-7, windows

Not sure what I did, but recently I have the minimized windows shown like this:

[image]

instead of the way before, with the window of that form, instead of a text as it is now.

Where can I change that option in Windows 7?

Comment: You disabled Aero Peak. Either through a setting, you disabled hardware accelleration, your graphics became slow, and windows set you to the classic theme, or you switched to the classic theme.

Comment: thx that was it, please post this as an answer, I had to click a button on that page after making driver updates, not sure what was the text in the button though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You disabled Aero Peak.

Either through a setting, you disabled hardware accelleration, your graphics became slow, and windows set you to the classic theme, or you switched to the classic theme.